# version compare error using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following python code which compares two versions v1 and v2 and outputs the following:

```
0 = version's are same
1 = v1 > v2
-1 = v2 > v1
```

code is as follows:

```
class Solution(object):
    def compareVersion(self, version1, version2):

        n1, n2 = len(version1), len(version2)
        i, j = 0, 0
        while i < n1 or j < n2:
            v1, v2 = 0, 0
            while i < n1 and version1[i] != '.':
                v1 = v1*10 + int(version1[i])
                i += 1
            while j < n2 and version2[j] != '.':
                v2 = v2*10 + int(version2[j])
                j += 1
            if v1 != v2:
                return 1 if v1 > v2 else -1
            i += 1
            j += 1

        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (Solution().compareVersion("2.10", "2.06"))
```

The above code outputs the following because v1> v2.

```
1
```

However when I type

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print (Solution().compareVersion("2.1", "2.06"))
```

the output is

```
-1`
```

How do I fix this here the output is incorrect due to missing zero.

Comment: FWIW, the semver specification states that version numbers should not contain leading zeros, so this input (and hence output) is questionable to begin with. https://semver.org/#spec-item-2

Comment: Even if you do allow leading zeros, it seems very odd for `2.1` to be short for `2.10`.

Comment: @chepner Indeed, OPs code's logic is a bit off anyway

Comment: @Ajinkya `2.10` is *"two point ten"*, not* *"two point one"*. These are not floating point numbers. They are integers divided by dots. Are you sure `compareVersion("2.1", "2.06")` should not return `-1`?

Comment: @DeepSpace That's a different issue (and makes sense). My point is that the comparisons become unnecessarily complicated when you allow an abbreviation for *one* special case. If `2.1 == 2.10`, then clearly you have to write `2.01` for the "real" minor version 1, and practically speaking you aren't going to have `2.20 == 2.2`, `2.30 == 2.3`, etc, so why not just require `2.10` to go along with all the other two-digit minor numbers and be done with it?

Comment: @chepner seems like OP is after their own specification :)

Comment: I posted the answer , got really valuable feedback

Answer (score 3):

Split the string at the dots and treat the numbers as integers:

```
>>> version_string = "2.06"
>>> version_as_integers = tuple(int(segment) for segment in version_string.split('.'))
>>> version_as_integers
(2, 6)
```

Then, just compare the versions:

```
if version_1_as_integers < version_2_as_integers:
    return -1
elif version_1_as_integers == version_2_as_integers:
    return 0
else:
    return 1
```

Complete solution:

```
def version_to_integers(version_string):
    return tuple(int(segment) for segment in version_string.split('.'))

def compare_versions(version_string_1, version_string_2):
    v1 = version_to_integers(version_string_1)
    v2 = version_to_integers(version_string_2)
    return ((v1 > v2) - (v1 < v2))
```

The last line is a trick from [a codegolf.stackexchange.com question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/49778/how-can-i-use-cmpa-b-with-python3)

Comment: python 2 could solve that in one line: `cmp(version_1_as_integers, version_2_as_integers)` but it's gone now, sob.

Comment: Looking at the example above, OP would like to have `2.1 > 2.06`, and `(2,1) < (2,6)`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I was just looking for what happened to `cmp` as well :)

Comment: @kszl True, OP wants `"2.1"` to behave like `"2.10"`, but that makes no sense, i.e. makes the task undefined. Why would it not be `"2.1000"` then instead? :\

Comment: @zvone I don't say it makes sense. It looks like OP thinks of that in a way where there's a dot between `0` and `6`. Otherwise, why would they call output `-1` of `compareVersion("2.1", "2.06")` incorrect?

Comment: @zvone you're right. If there's no fixed size or convention for the version numbers your solution is as good as any other.

Comment: I was following the wrong assumption for versioning I posted the answer which I thought is best

Answer (score -1):

With a bit research and @zvone and @DeepSpace comments to the original post. I found out this:

Versions are not floating point numbers, hence they do not fall under category of decimal numbers, hence the arithmetic of decimal numbers won't apply to versioning. According to semantic versioning 2.0.0 (https://semver.org/#spec-item-2) a version number should not be followed by leading zeros. Hence 2.06 is a bad versioning way to go. It should have been2.1, 2.6 etc to begin with. If you follow semantic versioning 2.0.0 you can avoid this dilema.

Answer (score -4):

Cast to a float instead of an int

```
>>> i = "2.10"
>>> j = "2.06"
>>> float(i) > float(j)
True
>>> i = "2.1"
>>> float(i) > float(j)
True
```

Comment: Version numbers are not floats; they can have more than 2 fields.

Comment: This will treat `"2.06"` as less than `"2.1"`, which is *probably* not desired and it won't handle `"2.06.11"` at all, which may be needed.